# Get json column data in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an events table with a permissions column of type json. But when I use dd($data->permission) or dd($data['permissions']) but it returns [] even though it has data.
I don't understand why it returns []

```
public function mount($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        dd($data['permissions']);
        if (isset($data['permissions']) && is_string($data['permissions'])) {
            $this->selectedUsers = json_decode($data['permissions'], true);
        } else {
            $this->selectedUsers = [];
        }
    }
```

data of $data

```
App\Models\EventsModel {#1479 ▼ // app\Livewire\Admin\Timekeeping\EditEvent.php:30
  #connection: "mysql"
  +table: "events"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:12 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "event_name" => "Chạy bộ 2"
    "event_key_checkin" => "1FpwDL8ZMXN5zvteWOWyxMZXpt9ogcSf"
    "event_key_checkout" => "Ewxe4hFFJuNnw6zE8CUP2TOqByTsj5JM"
    "location" => "{"address":"389 T\u00f4 k\u00fd, trung m\u1ef9 t\u00e2y, qu\u1eadn 12","located":{"latitude":"10.8511042","longitude":"106.6275269"},"type":"address"}"
    "event_time_start" => "2023-08-29 12:00:00"
    "event_time_end" => "2023-08-31 20:42:32"
    "created_at" => "2023-08-22 11:24:00"
    "updated_at" => "2023-09-03 20:19:40"
    "status" => 1
    "event_key_rollup" => "FqQouIfgm6kR7w5xOuYoli26RGTlK29Q"
    "permissions" => "[{"user_id": "6"}]"
  ]
  #original: array:12 [▶]
}
```

Comment: print ``$data->permissions``? Also, add your event model code

Comment: Do you define 
`protected $casts = ['permissions' => 'array'];` in your EventsModel class?